# Hiding the DataGridViewRow Top and Bottom Border Lines

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have a DataGridView called MyDataGrid1. Based on a field value I need to hide the bottom line for certain rows.

```
DataTable MyDtb = new DataTable();
MyDtb.Columns.Add("Colm_1", Type.GetType("System.String"));
MyDtb.Columns.Add("Colm_2", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
MyDtb.Columns.Add("Colm_3", Type.GetType("System.String"));

MyDataGrid1.DataSource = MyDtb;
```

I Have 2 requirements...

1. Once the user enters '5' in  Colm_2, then I want to remove the CellBorder Lines on the  Top and Bottom of the 4 rows below the CurrentRow
   Is this possible?
2. Also in the Form_load event I want to format MyDataGrid1, according to the value of Colm_2 like in requirement 01.
   Suppose Colm_2=2, then MyDataGrid1's Current Row and the following Rows Top and Bottom CellBorder Lines have to hide. Is this also possible?

Thanks

Comment: As an initial recommendation, I'd name those columns something more intuitive than "Colm_1" etc, otherwise refactoring your code is going to be a pain for somebody down the line.

Also, do you want the currentRow + the four rows beneath the currentRow to have their borders changed or is it just the four beneath?

Comment: Thanks Nick...I gave aa a sample column names..thanks for the comments..and Hereafter I will follow-up... Also I wish to have like Current Row + the following 4 rows...will be better....Thanks Again